# How can I sort a VBA MatchCollection by value of SubMatches(n)?

Tags: regex, vba, sorting, ms-word

I am relatively new to programming, and I wrote a Microsoft Word VBA macro that extracts a "parts list" from a patent description (the text of the active document), where each part reference in the list is identified in a rudimentary way as anything that looks like a numeric or all-caps alpha identifier of a part or feature preceded by up to four words in the same sentence.

What I have succeeded in doing so far is automatically opening a new Word document and inserting all unique part references line by line, in a format like

"10: providing a sewing machine 10," or "Q: of a heat flux Q."

I repeat the identifier at the beginning of each line so that the identifiers appear aligned at the left margin.

I also would like them to be sorted by identifier, which is m.SubMatches(2) of my regular expression MatchCollection m.  First the numbers in numerical order, then the alpha references in alphabetical order would be nice.

Any suggestions on how to go about this?  Here is a code snippet that sorts by the entire m.Value using a simple bubble-sort algorithm, without bothering to convert numeric identifiers to Long values:

```
Sub ExtractPartsList()

Dim re As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
Set re = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp


re.pattern = "((?:[A-Z]*[a-z]+[\s\n]+){0,3})(?=[A-Z]*[a-z]+[\s\n]+(?:\d+\b|[A-Z]+\b))" + _
"(\b[A-Z]*[a-z]+[\s\n]+)(\b\d+\b'*|[A-Z]+\b'*)" + _
"((?:\,[\s\n]+(?:\d+|[A-Z]+\b))+(?:\,?[\s\n]+and[\s\n+](?:\d+|[A-Z]+\b))?)?(?:[\s\n]+and[\s\n]+(?:\d+|[A-Z]+\b))?"


' m.Value is the whole matched string
' m.SubMatches(1) is the word immediately preceding the part number / alpha reference
' m.SubMatches(2) is the part number / alpha reference

re.IgnoreCase = False
re.Global = True

Dim txt As String
Dim bigString As String
bigString = ""
Dim allLongMatches As MatchCollection, m As Match
Dim partNameLastWord As String
Dim partReference As String
Dim partNameAndReference As String
Dim partsColl As New Collection
Dim partsList() As String
Dim i As Long
    txt = ActiveDocument.Range.text

      If re.Test(txt) Then

        Set allLongMatches = re.Execute(txt)
        Documents.Add DocumentType:=wdNewBlankDocument
        For Each m In allLongMatches
            Debug.Print m.Value, "Sbm 1 = " + m.SubMatches(1), "Sbm 2 = " + m.SubMatches(2), "Sbm 3 = " + m.SubMatches(3)
            If InStr(bigString, LCase(m.SubMatches(1) + m.SubMatches(2))) = 0 _
                And InStr(LCase(m.Value), "of claim " + m.SubMatches(2)) = 0 _
                And InStr(LCase(m.SubMatches(2)), "fig") = 0 Then
            bigString = bigString + LCase(m.Value)
            partsColl.Add m.SubMatches(2) + ": " + m.Value


             End If
            Next m

       End If


     ReDim partsList(1 To partsColl.Count)

     For i = 1 To partsColl.Count
     partsList(i) = partsColl(i)
       Next i


' BubbleSort (partsList())
' Instead of calling BubbleSort (partsList())
' I apparently still have to learn how to properly call methods I
' have written - for now I am just embedding it here:

  Dim strTemp As String
'  Dim i As Long
  Dim j As Long
  Dim lngMin As Long
  Dim lngMax As Long
  lngMin = LBound(partsList())
  lngMax = UBound(partsList())
  For i = lngMin To lngMax - 1
    For j = i + 1 To lngMax
      If partsList(i) > partsList(j) Then
        strTemp = partsList(i)
        partsList(i) = partsList(j)
        partsList(j) = strTemp
      End If
    Next j
  Next i

    For i = 1 To partsColl.Count
    Selection.InsertAfter (partsList(i))
    Selection.InsertParagraphAfter
     Next i


    End Sub

    Sub BubbleSort(arr)
      Dim strTemp As String
      Dim i As Long
      Dim j As Long
      Dim lngMin As Long
      Dim lngMax As Long
      lngMin = LBound(arr)
      lngMax = UBound(arr)
      For i = lngMin To lngMax - 1
        For j = i + 1 To lngMax
          If arr(i) > arr(j) Then
            strTemp = arr(i)
            arr(i) = arr(j)
            arr(j) = strTemp
          End If
        Next j
      Next i
    End Sub
```

Sample input from U.S. Pat. No. 6,293,874:

"The second post 44 is positioned a sufficient distance from the first post 24 to permit the user to require the user to bend forward at the waist in a stooped position between the posts 24, 44. The user is thus positioned to predominantly present his or her buttocks B toward the plurality of rotating arms 56 that are detachably mounted on the second post 44 at a height generally level with the user's buttocks. The second post 44 is mountable on the surface of the platform 12 by a detachable collar 46 and connector bolts or screws."

Output (only works nicely because the numbers are the same length - I imagine it is really sorting "alphabetically," where "2" would come after "19," for example):

```
' 12: surface of the platform 12
' 24: from the first post 24
' 24: position between the posts 24, 44
' 44: The second post 44
' 46: by a detachable collar 46
' 56: plurality of rotating arms 56
' B: his or her buttocks B
```

Comment: The quesion is missing a descriptive sample of input text and expected output for it.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Edited to add sample input and output and a RegExp pattern that will do for purposes of illustrating my sorting problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a klunky solution that works by creating a separate array of the part identifiers by themselves and sorting the partsList() array in parallel with the identifier array id() As Long.  Setting alpha identifiers to zero for now and letting them percolate to the top unsorted; there are not usually enough of them to worry about sorting alphabetically.  I hesitate to mark this as an answer, as I would still like to see if someone will chime in with a more elegant/direct solution.

```
Sub ExtractPartsList()

Dim re As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
Set re = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp


re.pattern = "((?:[A-Z]*[a-z]+[\s\n]+){0,3})(?=[A-Z]*[a-z]+[\s\n]+(?:\d+\b|[A-Z]+\b))" + _
"(\b[A-Z]*[a-z]+[\s\n]+)(\b\d+\b'*|[A-Z]+\b'*)" + _
"((?:\,[\s\n]+(?:\d+|[A-Z]+\b))+(?:\,?[\s\n]+and[\s\n+](?:\d+|[A-Z]+\b))?)?(?:[\s\n]+and[\s\n]+(?:\d+|[A-Z]+\b))?"


' m.Value is the whole matched string
' m.SubMatches(1) is the word immediately preceding the part number / alpha reference
' m.SubMatches(2) is the part number / alpha reference

re.IgnoreCase = False
re.Global = True   


Dim txt As String
Dim bigString As String
bigString = ""
Dim allLongMatches As MatchCollection, m As Match
Dim partNameLastWord As String
Dim partReference As String
Dim partNameAndReference As String
Dim partsColl As New Collection
Dim idColl As New Collection
' for now not using this variable:
' Dim referenceTextColl As New Collection
Dim partsList() As String
Dim id() As Long
' Dim referenceText() As String
' Dim partsListSorted() As String
Dim i As Long

  txt = ActiveDocument.Range.text

  If re.Test(txt) Then

    Set allLongMatches = re.Execute(txt)
    Documents.Add DocumentType:=wdNewBlankDocument
    For Each m In allLongMatches
        Debug.Print m.Value, "Sbm 1 = " + m.SubMatches(1), "Sbm 2 = " + m.SubMatches(2), "Sbm 3 = " + m.SubMatches(3)
        If InStr(bigString, LCase(m.SubMatches(1) + m.SubMatches(2))) = 0 _
            And InStr(LCase(m.Value), "of claim " + m.SubMatches(2)) = 0 _
            And InStr(LCase(m.SubMatches(2)), "fig") = 0 Then
        bigString = bigString + LCase(m.Value)
        partsColl.Add m.SubMatches(2) + ": " + m.Value
        idColl.Add (m.SubMatches(2))
        ' referenceTextColl.Add (m.Value)


   '      Selection.InsertAfter (m.SubMatches(2) + ": ")
   '      Selection.InsertAfter (m.Value)
   '      Selection.InsertParagraphAfter

         End If
        Next m

   End If

 ReDim partsList(1 To partsColl.Count)
 ReDim id(1 To partsColl.Count)
 ' ReDim referenceText(1 To partsColl.Count)

 For i = 1 To partsColl.Count
 partsList(i) = partsColl(i)
 id(i) = 0
 ' Deal with "prime" symbols #' and convert numeric identifiers to Long:
 If IsNumeric(Replace(idColl(i), "'", "")) Then id(i) = CLng(Replace(idColl(i), "'", ""))

referenceText(i) = referenceTextColl(i)
   Next i


'
' I apparently still have to learn how to properly call methods I
' have written - I am just embedding a bubble sort algorithm here instead:

  Dim idTemp As String
  Dim referenceTemp As String
  Dim partsListLineTemp As String
'  Dim i As Long
  Dim j As Long
  Dim lngMin As Long
  Dim lngMax As Long
  lngMin = LBound(partsList())
  lngMax = UBound(partsList())
  For i = lngMin To lngMax - 1
    For j = i + 1 To lngMax
      If id(i) > id(j) Then
        idTemp = id(i)
        partsList(i) = partsList(j)
        id(i) = id(j)
        partsList(j) = partsListLineTemp
        id(j) = idTemp
      End If
    Next j
  Next i

For i = 1 To partsColl.Count
Selection.InsertAfter (partsList(i))
Selection.InsertParagraphAfter
 Next i
        partsListLineTemp = partsList(i)


End Sub
```